# ASP.NET page validation

Tags: asp.net, validation

I have a requirement wherein I have a bunch of about 10 aspx pages.The user shall be able to go from one screen to another using navigation.All the range , custom,regex validators need to file so that data enetered is correct.Required fields need not be entered at this stage and the user can skip required fields. On the last page, I need to find out all the fields which are required and if incomplete want to show the user, these fields are required, sort of summary with link to the page where the control was left blank.
Does any one have any good ideas to achive validation on pages which the user has left and can do validation at the very end before the data is submitted. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For what its worth, this is a really terrible UI Experience... If they're required, then make them type it in at the time. No one wants to use a wizard, where they have to click through 10 pages of information only to be told at the end to go back put more information in

Comment: Whether this is a terrible UI Experience or not depends upon the type of data collected. I once created an online job application system and most of the questions were long and quite detailed. In our testing, we found people often wanted to enter this in a random order and were quite frustrated when they couldn't. However, for a simpler checkout or registration process, particularly where steps depend on earlier steps then validation as you go is definitely preferred.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Validators form part of the page on which they lie. You cannot use the built-in validator controls to validate input fields on previous pages in the sequence. If you must do it this way, then you should implement your own validation framework which validates data on each page, but provides feedback on the summary page.

You should look into the usability issues faced if you only give feedback to the user at the end of the sequence of pages. He/she will be required to go back a few pages and retry input there. I don't think that is a good option at all.

A much better option would be to use the ASP.NET Wizard control (which loads sequential UI in separate panels, but on the same page). That would enable you to use Validators in conjunction with your setup. [This article](http://steveorr.net/articles/Wizard.aspx) by Steve C. Orr provides a good introduction to using Validators with the Wizard control.

Alternatively, you can use the AJAX Tab control as others have suggested.

Comment: Wizard was the first thing that popped into my head.

Comment: The pages I am using are too large to be incorporated into a wizard control, would not like to use wizard as the page gets locked by one developer in source control when he/she edits. Any other approaches

Comment: @chugh97 - use UserControls as the steps of the wizard.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using i.e. a TabControl (ships with the Ajax Control Toolkit).

Answer (score 0):

Same thing I am applying in Asp.net MVC but I suggest you to use Tab control rather to use Bunch of pages as sshow posted.